# Why big numbers show only two reference even when you define new variables?

Tags: python

When i use getrefcount method in sys module and try to count reference of certain big numbers (in this example 1000000) it shows two references. Now I know that these two references could be used by IDLE or python itself (as per the book) but when i introduce a variable a = 1000000 it should show 3 references but still shows 2. Any idea why this happens ?

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.getrefcount(1000000)
2
>>> a = 1000000
>>> sys.getrefcount(1000000)
2
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be assuming that every time you have `1000000` in your code, that refers to the same object.  That's not the case.

What you have in your code are three different, unrelated `1000000` objects:

```
In [1]: id(1000000)
Out[1]: 4328822600

In [2]: id(1000000)
Out[2]: 4328822504
```

If you try a small integer instead, those get interned (at least by my interpreter) and so refcounts do increase:

```
In [7]: sys.getrefcount(3)
Out[7]: 284

In [8]: a = 3

In [9]: sys.getrefcount(3)
Out[9]: 287
```

Comment: Yes, in my interpreter too small integer objects' reference increases when i introduce a variable but the same does not happen with big numbers. I was a little confused by this as i had a feeling that python was treating the two big numbers as two different objects but i am not able to understand why this is only increasing for small numbers and not for big ones.

BTW , In your code with a single variable introduction the reference jumps from 284 to 287 , this is interesting as in my code in IDLE it only increases by one. :)

Comment: This is wrong as per Python3.7. References to the same value are stored as one value, with two pointers towards it. This saves resources. Try comparing the ids of the two values of a in `a=(1,1)`

Answer (score 1):

You are counting the references of the literal `1000000` twice.

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.getrefcount(1000000)
3
>>> a = 1000000
>>> sys.getrefcount(a)
2
>>> b = a
>>> sys.getrefcount(a)
3
```

---

**Edit**

This really seems to work differently for small and larger numbers. Assigning small numbers actually references the same object as seen by `id`:

```
>>> import sys
>>> id(42)
8831008
>>> sys.getrefcount(42)
17
>>> a = 42
>>> id(a)
8831008
>>> id(42)
8831008
>>> sys.getrefcount(42)
18
```

For larger numbers the behaviour differs:

```
>>> import sys
>>> id(123456)
140049615070320
>>> sys.getrefcount(123456)
3
>>> a = 123456
>>> id(a)  # `a` references the literal from before
140049615070320
>>> id(123456)  # but a new literal of the same value is a different object
140049615070192
>>> sys.getrefcount(123456)
3
```

Also the behaviour differs across implementations of Python:

**Python 3.6 on Mac:**

```
Python 3.6.7 (v3.6.7:6ec5cf24b7, Oct 20 2018, 03:02:14) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> id(123456)
4452257552
>>> id(123456)
4452257552
>>> id(123456)
4452257552
>>> id(123456)
4452257552
>>> id(123456)
4452257552
>>> id(123456)
4452257552  # the literal is always the same object
>>> a = 123456
>>> id(a)
4452257552  # `a` references the same object as the literal before
>>> id(123456)
4452257648  # but the literal now references a new object
>>> id(123456)
4452257648  # a second time
>>> id(123456)
4449747760  # but every third time it references a new object
>>> id(123456)
4449747760
>>> id(123456)
4452257584
>>> id(123456)
4452257584
>>> id(123456)
4449750704
>>> id(123456)
4449750704
>>> id(123456)
4452257648
>>> id(123456)
4452257648
```

**Python 3.7 on Linux:**

```
Python 3.6.7 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:32:17) 
[GCC 8.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> id(123456)
140385586909904
>>> id(123456)
140385586909904
>>> id(123456)
140385586909904
>>> id(123456)
140385586909904
>>> id(123456)
140385586909904
>>> id(123456)
140385586909904
>>> a = 123456
>>> id(a)  # `a` references the same object as the literal before
140385586909904
>>> id(123456)  # the literal references a new object
140385586910320
>>> id(123456)
140385586910320
>>> id(123456)
140385586910320
>>> id(123456)
140385586910320
>>> id(123456)
140385586910320
>>> id(123456)
140385586910320
>>> id(123456)
140385586910320
>>> id(123456)
140385586910320
>>> b = 123456
>>> id(b)  # until it is assigned to a variable
140385586910320
>>> id(123456)  # then the literal references another new object
140385586910224
>>> id(123456)
140385586910224
>>> id(123456)
140385586910224
>>> id(123456)
140385586910224
>>> id(123456)
140385586910224
>>> id(123456)
140385586910224
```

---

Ultimately this seems to be an *implementation detail* which your code should not rely upon.

Comment: I am not sure about this. In IDLE it works as below and always shows two references.
```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.getrefcount(1000000)
2
>>> a = 1000000
>>> sys.getrefcount(1000000)
2
>>> b = a
>>> sys.getrefcount(1000000)
2
>>> 
```

Answer (score 1):

After the first call to sys.getrefcount(1000000) the literal 1000000 reference count is back to zero - nothing references it.

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.getrefcount(1000000) 
2     # The literal 1000000 is created/referenced (1) and +getrefcount (1) = (2)
>>> a = 1000000 # The literal 1000000 is created/referenced (1)
>>> sys.getrefcount(1000000)
2     # The literal exists, so its references (1) and from getrefcount (1) = (2)
```

Here is the sample program with a random number (can be changed to any particular you like to test):

```
import sys
import random

number = random.randint(1, 1000000)
print(number, sys.getrefcount(number), "print got count too")
print(sys.getrefcount(number), "one less")
x = []
for i in range(100):
    x.append(number)

print(sys.getrefcount(number), "plus 100")

del x

print(sys.getrefcount(number), "back to original")
save = number
print(sys.getrefcount(number), "extra one")
del number
print(sys.getrefcount(save), "minus one one")
save_str = str(save)
del save
print(sys.getrefcount(int(save_str)), "only one")
```

Output:

```
3926 3 print got count too
2 one less
102 plus 100
2 back to original
3 extra one
2 minus one one
1 only one
```

The getrefcount is 1 when the number represented as string only at the end.

Comment: Interesting , may i ask why this only happens for big numbers and not for small ones.

Comment: At my Python console the first small number referenced 3 was 257: the same behavior as big number 1000000.

Comment: Small numbers like 0 and 1, and so on up to 257 already exist and referenced by build-ins when you load Python.